# How to pass HTML tag from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 $.post('AddDocument',
                        { Title: $('#Title').val(), Description: $('#Description').val(),DocumentBody: '<p>aaaa</p>' },
                         function (data, status, obj) {

                        });
                }
            });
```

this is the code from my view to call the server side code my problem is when im about to pass the string HTML tag in controller its not working any idea? im having a hardtime with this thank you.. look at the DocumentBody its a string but its not working the controller didnt get the value is it because its a HTML???

Comment: You need to stop your controller method from validating input using, ValidateInput(false) in your controller, [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]

Answer (score 4):

just in your Model add [AllowHtml] attribute

```
[AllowHtml]
public string DocumentBody { get; set; }
```

Comment: after adding [AllowHtml] it has an error Namespace Could not be found(Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what user2675751 suggested, another option would be to set `ValidateInput(false)` on your controller's action:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AddDocument(MyViewModel viewModel) {
   // your code here
}
```